# How to make update endpoint more general purpose? (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a `function` in my API to update the name of a person in an SQLite database. You give it the ID of the name you wish to change and the new name.

How can I build a `function` in a way that allows me to update a wide range of fields in the `database`? even things from different `tables`?

I started off trying to use parameters to switch which SQL query is executed, but this feels a bit clunky and not scalable. Is there a better way?

Current code:

```
 private function json_update_authors() {
  $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


 $query  = "UPDATE authors SET name = :name WHERE authorId = :authorId";
 $params = ["name" => $input->name, "authorId" => $input->authorId];
 $res = $this->recordset->getJSONRecordSet($query, $params);    
 return json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message" => "ok"));
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with database that you are using.

Comment: @Popeye Done. Also listed in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prependix

You can achieve what you want, but before reading the details, I recommend contemplating about what you would like to restrict this to, because if there is a file your function blindly trusts, then, should malicious input be inside that file, your database can easily be hacked. So, you should have a whitelist of tables/fields that you allow to be updated and apply that.

## Decoding JSON

`json_decode` decodes your JSON into an object that you do not foresee its members. However, according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) you can iterate this object like:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

However, [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) can decode your JSON into an `array` as well, like:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

I personally prefer to decode JSON into arrays, but you can operate with the first approach as well. In both cases, you can iterate the array in a similar manner as described above.

## Recommended format

Your update has an anatomy as follows:

- table
- fields
- filter

So, I would recommend that you could use a JSON representation of your input, that has a `tableName` field, which is a `string`, a `fields` field, which is an `array` of key-value pairs, the keys representing the fields to be updated and the values representing the values to update to and finally a `filter` field, which, if we intend to be very elegant, could also be an `array` of objects of key-value pairs, the keys representing the fields you are to filter by and the values representing the values you would filter with. A sample Javascript object that would comply to this format would look like the following:

```
[
    { //Your query
        tableName: 'authors',
        fields: 
        [
            {
                name: 'somename'
            }
        ],
        filters:
        [
            {
                authorId: 123
            }
        ]
    },
    { //Some other example
        tableName: 'books',
        fields: 
        [
            {
                isbn: 'someisbn',
                title: 'sometitle'
            }
        ],
        filters:
        [
            {
                pageNumber: 123,
                weight: '5kg'
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I have given an example above, of two objects, so you can see that:

- several updates can be notified in the JSON
- you can update several fields in a single command
- you can filter by several fields

I should mention that this is a rabbit hole, because you might want to vary the operator as well, but since this is a mere answer, I do not write a full elegant project for its purpose. Instead of that, let me just tell you that there is a lot of room for improvement, operator dynamicity springs to mind instantly as an improvement that you may need.

## How to generate an update query:

```
//assuming that $JSON is a variable holding such values as describe in the previous chapter
foreach ($JSON as $obj) {
    $tableName = $obj['tableName'];
    $fields = [];
    $filters = [];
    $params = [];
    $toExecute = isset($whiteList['tables'][$tableName]);
    foreach ($obj['fields'] as $key => $value) {
        $fields[]=($key.'=:field_value'.$key);
        $params['field_value'.$key] = $value;
        $toExecute = $toExecute && isset($whiteList['fields'][$key]);
    }
    foreach ($obj['filters'] as $key => $value) {
        $filters[]=($key.'=:filter_value'.$key);
        $params['filter_value'.$key] = $value;
        $toExecute = $toExecute && isset($whiteList['filters'][$key]);
    }
}
```

I have used a whitelist above to make sure that the queries will not update tables/fields using filters where the name of the table/field/filter is either badly formatted, malicious or unwanted. This code is untested, it might well contain typos, but the idea should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your time!